# Rails 3 - own validation message isntead of "is not a number"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check in my app, that input value should be integer and **couldn't** be empty or nil.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :event_cost, :presence => { :message => "can't be empty..." }

  validates :event_cost, 
              :numericality => { :only_integer => { :message => "should be only integer" } } 
end
```

So, if user prints nothing in the field i get message `"Event cost is not a number"`. How can i set my own message instead of that?

Comment: The rails way is to use locales\en.yml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :event_cost, :presence => { :message => "can't be empty..." }

  validates :event_cost, 
              :numericality => { :message => "Your own message", :only_integer => true } 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it will work fine as you didn't set only_integer to true it was not working properly

```
:event_cost, 
          :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :message => "should be only integer"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this

validates :event_cost, 
              :numericality => { :only_integer => true,{ :message => "should be only integer" } }